# Why does IE (IE8, specifically) not highlight selected option in a multi select box which is disabled?

Tags: html, css, jsp, internet-explorer-8, multi-select

I am having a multi select box in a JSP page which has some options and is disabled.

```
<select id="mySelectBox" multiple disabled>
    <option value="first" selected>First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
    <option value="fourth" selected>Fourth</option>
</select>
```

I have the first and the fourth options selected, but they are not highlighted in IE They are properly highlighted when I use Firefox.

Is there any solution or workaround for this?

**EDIT:** My DOCTYPE is `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
But even with that I don't see any difference.

Comment: have you tried `selected="selected"` ?

Comment: @Justinas Tried it where?

Comment: inside option tag: `<option value="first" selected="selected">First</option>`

Comment: @Justinas I guess I have tried that also.

Comment: What is your `<!DOCTYPE>`? It might be that IE8 simply does not support styling disabled `<select>` lists

Comment: @UweB What should the `<!DOCTYPE>` ideally be for IE8 to support styling?

Comment: I don't think there's an ideal setting really, IE8 is "special", and not the good kind of special. ;-)
I tried to reproduce the issue by forcing my IE11 to IE8 mode, there it works as expected (on various doctypes)

Comment: @UweB Can you paste here one such doctype?

Comment: Ideally, use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for modern browsers (for HTML5). `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` would be for IE quirks mode, more standard again with `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`.

Comment: IMHO the best workaround would be not to use a `select` with `multiple` in the first place, because they are a usability nightmare, since the average user doesn't know he has to hold down the control key. Use checkboxes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, [this](http://www.jefclaes.be/2010/02/ie8-fix-disabled-select-not-showing.html) CSS workaround seems to have fixed  my issue!!

```
select[disabled="disabled"][multiple="multiple"]{
    background-color:#D4D0C8;
} 
select[disabled="disabled"][multiple="multiple"] option[selected="selected"]{
    background-color:navy;
}
```

Interesting because, earlier I had used the same to no effect. Perhaps I had missed out on something then.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i clearly understand what you want to do, but i can sugest to do it with little jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#mySelectBox option:selected").css('background','black');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you suggest the same using JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need a pure js?