# Why does IE8 not highlight selected option in a multi select box which is disabled? But in higher version's it was working fine?

Tags: select, internet-explorer-8, background-color, invisible, disabled-control

I have tried some solutions provided in previous posts([click here to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881640/why-does-ie-ie8-specifically-not-highlight-selected-option-in-a-multi-select)) . But it's not working for me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is, why are you still using IE?

Comment: Because it's a BFSI project . They will mostly use IE only . @Coal_